# Change Ruby Path without RVM

Tags: ruby, linux, path

I'm not in the position to use RVM because I'm working with a predefined OS and a proxy.

I'm working on CentOS7 and my application uses `ruby 2.3.1`. This comes pre-installed on this specific system. CentOS7 supports ruby up to `2.0.0`.

My problem is when I install KDE for a shell it installs ruby 2.0.0 and overrides certain paths so when I use `ruby -v` I now use `2.0.0` which is not good!

If I do `which -a ruby` I get

```
/usr/bin/ruby
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby
```

If I do `echo $PATH` I get

```
/opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

The Ruby I want to use is installed in `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin` but `/usr/bin` comes before it. Is that the reason why CentOS7 is using that version of Ruby instead of the pre-installed Ruby 2.3.1 version in `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin`?

If so, how do I change the order of the path?

Answer (score 2):

> The Ruby I want to use is installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin but /usr/bin comes before it. Is that the reason why CentOS7 is using that version of Ruby instead of the pre-installed Ruby 2.3.1 version in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin?

Yes, it is the reason.

> how do I change the order of the path?

You can redefine the `$PATH` in your `~/.bashrc`. Just add this line at the bottom:

```
export PATH="/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:$PATH"
```